# mixing rtl with ltr flutter text

Tags: flutter, text, hebrew, register-transfer-level

my "(" ")" get flipped when I try to write text with Hebrew (rtl).
I look up in the internet but its don't work for me like:

```
      locale: const Locale('he', 'IL'),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('he', 'IL'),
        const Locale('en', '')
      ], 
.
.
.
```

and:

`return Directionality(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, child: TabsScreen());`

after a lot of test I find that the problem trigger when the phone settings is on English or another language but if the settings on Hebrew is work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direction in text field to switch between rtl and ltr

```
Text(
direction : selectedLanguage == 'hebrew' ? TextDirection.rtl:TextDirection.ltr, 
)
```

Comment: Thank but how I do it when I have a long text together like אבג?)

Comment: The problem trigger when the phone settings that on the web on English and not on Hebrew and then all the text get flipped.

Comment: So you wish to find the data and switch the direction?

Comment: yes but I found why the problem happen when I build to web... I need to build => flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit

Comment: any reason why it wasn't working in html renderer?